# What should be the sector image size for 26 sectors in rotary wheel iOS?

Tags: ios, sector, spinning

I am following [How To Create a Rotating Wheel Control with UIKit](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit) tutorial to create a spinning wheel.

I have `26 sectors` in my wheel. The sector image provided on this site is overlapping each other for 26 sectors. What should be the ideal size of sector image to fit appropriately.

[image]

Comment: Uh? Obviously the sector image should have the shape of a pie piece, with an angle of  2*M_PI/26. Do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: You understood it right. The tutorial's sector image is in the ratio 90:70, so in this case also the size should be same?

Comment: What's important is that it should be in the shape of a pie piece of the correct angle, with the rest of the image transparent. What the actual HxW size of the image is, is then not that important (the current size you're using looks ok).